# Identifiers Errors

Tags: java, html

I have some problems with my code im trying to validade if the HTML file that my program reads have identifier in in case it have perfect the problem is that when my .java reads the file and create the .txt that it have to generate the program reads everything as a identifier

```
        String line;
        int lineNumber = 1;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Write enumerated lines to the output file
            writer.write(String.format("%04d", lineNumber) + " " + line + "\n"); 
           
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

            for (String token : tokens) {
                // Use regular expression to validate the identifier
                if (!token.matches("[a-zA-Z_\\p{L}][\\p{L}0-9_]*")) {
                    // If the token is not a valid identifier, write to the output file
                    writer.write("Error at line " + lineNumber + ": Invalid token -> " + token + "\n");
                } else {
                    // If the token is an identifier, check if it's a reserved word in JavaScript
                    boolean isReserved = false;
                    for (String reserved : ReservedWords) {
                        if (token.equals(reserved)) {
                            // If the token matches a reserved word, mark it as reserved
                            isReserved = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

`Error on line 1: Invalid identifier -> <!DOCTYPE`
`Error on line 1: Invalid identifier -> html>`
`Error on line 1: Invalid identifier -> <html>`
`Error on line 1: Invalid identifier -> <head>`

the .txt show me this, but I just need to show me error if the identifier is wrong,not every single line in the code.

Comment: If you're looking for an error in a specific spot, try isolating it and putting it into its own test document. However, given the question, the errors _do_ seem to be about the identifier being wrong.

Comment: The way you are processing your HTML, that's exactly the behaviour you should expect. `html>` is certainly not a valid identifier. You must [edit] your question and explain what output you are expecting. Perhaps you need to use an HTML parser.